# Prevent restarting JS code when linking to anchor

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple navigation menu linking to different parts of my page using an anchor tag like this

```
        <a href="#section-2">Blabla</a>
```

The problem is that I have some JS fading the section in when opening the page but it's also triggered each time I click on the anchor. How to prevent this?

I don't want this, I want to execute my JS at page opening and do nothing (except going to the right section of the page) when clicking on anchor tag

The page is not reloading so I don't understand why this is happening.

Is it because of turbolinks ?

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  fadeoutImg();
  fadeInText();
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could make a global event handler with a conditional that checks the event being triggered. Place a data attribute or class in the a tags that handle the anchor tags and check those, if they are present then by pass your fade event.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dale! I can try that, where should I add the conditional though? I'm confused
Thanks a lot

Comment: Why are you using turbolinks for the fade functions? Perhaps if you added more code and explain how turbolinks is involved? Maybe adding a reproducible example may also help...